# Como enviar e-mail através de uma página em HTML?

Tags: html, envio-de-email

Como enviar um e-mail para um destinatário estabelecido em uma página `HTML`?

Comment: Eu acho que isso já foi respondido antes. De qualquer forma você precisa dar mais detalhes do que já fez. O que já posso dizer é que essencialmente não dá para mandar diretamente da página de forma padrão e confiável.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1ª OPÇÃO:**

1º Utilizei o MandrilJS que é um serviço que me envia 12 Mil emails de forma gratuita pra você (isso não é spam). funciona como meio de campo para não precisar de um servidor.

Link para acesso (é necessário criar uma conta): [MandrilJS](https://www.mandrill.com/)

2º Crie um formulário comum e (coloque como `method` `POST` só pra não encher a URL mas nada será enviado para um servidor) no botão de envio faça-o desta forma:

```
<button onClick="sendMail();return false;">Enviar</button>
```

3º Crie um `Javascript` com uma função de mesmo nome que a do botão que irá recuperar os campos preenchidos pelo usuário do formulário:

```
function sendMail(){
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var assunto = document.getElementById("assunto").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
    var body = '<strong>Nome: </strong>'+nome+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Email: </strong>'+email+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Assunto: </strong>'+assunto+'<br />'+
               '<strong>Descição: </strong>'+desc;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data:{
                'key':'sua chave aqui',
                'message':{
                    'from_email':'email que irá enviar',
                    'to':[
                        {
                            'email':'email remetente',
                            'name':'Seu Nome (ou nick)',
                            'type':'to'
                        }
                    ],
                    'subject':'Assunto',
                    'html':body
                }
            }
    });
}
```

**OBS1:** Não é necessário inserir suas senhas de email em local algum, você deverá somente se cadastrar no `MandrilJS` (sem inserir senha de seus emails) e gerar uma chave, chave esta que será inserida no json no local especifico (ela é gerado nas configurações).

**OBS2:** É necessário jQuery.

**OBS3:** Pode inserir o CSS nas tags

**OBS4:** Ambos os Emails tem de ser validos o Destinatário por rasões obvias ele irá receber os emails, o Remente por que o MandriJS envia semanalmente as estatísticas de envios e leituras dos email.

**2ª OPÇÃO:**

Utilizo a classe PHPMailer para este fim (é necessário pelo menos um GMAIL para isso já que usaremos seu servidor SMTP) estou colocando uns métodos que fazem o uso desta classe (todo documentado).

**Link para download da PHPMailer:** http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

```
    /**
    *String que armazena o email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
    *@var string
    */
    const GUSER = 'email';

    /**
    *String que armazena a senha do email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
    *@var string
    */
    const GPWD = 'senha';

    /**
    *String que armazena o email para qual as mensagens serão enviadas (destinatário).
    *@var string
    */
    const GSEND = 'teste';


   static function contactUsEmail(){

        $emailRemetente = $_POST['email'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mensagem = $_POST["message"];
        $corpoMensagem = '<b>CONCTACT US EMAIL</b>'.'<br /><b>Email Remetente: </b>'.$emailRemetente.
        '<br /><b>Nome:</b>'.$name.'<br /><b>Assunto:</b>'.$subject.'<br /><b>Mensagem:</b>'.$mensagem;

        $sendResult = SendEmail::smtpMailer(SendEmail::GSEND, SendEmail::GUSER, $name, $subject, $corpoMensagem);

        if($sendResult === true){
             echo 'Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso';
        }else{
            echo $sendResult;
        }
    }

    function smtpMailer($destinatario, $remetente, $nomeRemetente, $assunto, $corpo){

        /*
        *Objeto que realizará a composição do email com os dados passados como parametros, 
        *armazenara as configurações do servidor SMTP utilizado e todas as outras configurações 
        *e realizará o envio do email.
        *@var PHPMailer object
        */
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        /**
        *Define o charset do email a ser enviado.
        */
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        /**
        *Ativa SMTP para uso.
        */
        $mail->IsSMTP();

        /**
        *Não exibirá erros e mensagens, outras configurações possiveis: 
        *Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas.
        */
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

        /**
        *Ativa a autenticação.
        */
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        /**
        *Protocolo utilizado, o gmail (servidor utilizado) requere o uso de tls.
        */
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        /**
        *SMTP utilizado
        */
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

        /**
        *Porta utilizado para envio de mensagens (ela deverá estar aberta em seu servidor).
        */
        $mail->Port = 587;

        /**
        *Login do usuário utilizado para envio do email (no caso usuário comum do gmail).
        */
        $mail->Username = SendEmail::GUSER;

        /**
        *Senha do login de usuário utilizado para envio do email.
        */
        $mail->Password = SendEmail::GPWD;

        /**
        *Identificação do remetente do email (usuário de email utilizado para envio do 
        *email pelo sistema (logo de propriedade do sistema) e o nome do usuário remetente 
        *(informado na hora da criação do email)) do email.
        */
        $mail->SetFrom($remetente, $nomeRemetente);

        /**
        *Assunto do email.
        */
        $mail->Subject = $assunto;

        /**
        *Corpo do email.
        */
        $mail->Body = $corpo;

        /**
        *Email destinatário do email (de propriedade do sistema).
        */
        $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);

        /**
        *Seta o email como HTML (por padrão ele é text/plain).
        */
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $sendResult = $mail->Send();

        if(!$sendResult){
            return "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: O Mandrill é muito bom, mas eu sempre usei pelo servidor. Não tem problema expor a chave da API no cliente?

Comment: @bfavaretto Olha eu me fiz esta pergunta porém na documentação fala que não há problemas, e pra fazer login na conta é necessário o username e senha a key não é usada hora nenhuma.

Comment: Mas quem pegar essa chave poderia mandar emails no seu nome, e usando sua cota do Mandrill. Acho que essa API em JS foi criada para uso no Node, não em browsers.

Comment: Se não me falha a memoria há como organizar campanhas com cada chave que você gera (você pode gerar varias chaves).

Comment: Sim, mas meu ponto é: se você pode fazer algo só com a chave, quem conhece a chave pode fazer o mesmo. (Não estou questionando sua resposta, inclusive ela dá outras opções e votei +1 nela; só estou tentando esclarecer essa questão do Mandrill).

Comment: Vou verificar se é possível restringir a origem dos emails pelo servidor do Mandrill

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25798/discussion-between-ricardo-and-bfavaretto).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o elemento `a` informando no atributo `href` os detalhes do email tais como assunto (`subject`), destinatário (`mailto:`) e corpo da mensagem (`body`). Os espaços em branco separando cada palavra no assunto e texto da mensagem devem ser informados como a combinação de caracteres `%20`.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="mailto:algum@email.com?subject=Assunto%20da%20mensagem&body=Conteúdo%20da%20mensagem">Enviar email</a>
```

Comment: Isso não envia um email, simplesmente abre o cliente configurado pelo navegador com os campos preenchidos, não parece ser o que o AP deseja.